# Как запустить класс в фоновом режиме?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin

У меня есть приложение (`xamarin.android`), оно принимает push-сообщения. Я хочу вывести эти сообщения в `TextBox`, но они выводятся только тогда, когда приложение работает на переднем плане. Как сделать так, чтобы оно принимало сообщения, даже когда приложение не запущено?

Мой код:

```
 [Service]

    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {

        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
        //public override void OnMessageSent(string msgId) { }

        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
            SendNotification(message.GetNotification().Body, message.Data);


        }

        public void SendNotification(string messageBody, IDictionary<string, string> data)
        {


            MainActivity.JsonWiew.Text = messageBody.Replace("\r\n", "");;
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            foreach (string key in data.Keys)
            {
                intent.PutExtra(key, data[key]);
            }
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                //.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .SetContentText(messageBody)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Но не могли бы вы помочь как это реализовать в xamarin?

Comment: Я добавлял вот эти строки в MainActivity: `var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(FirebaseMessagingService));
            StartService(intent);` Но не выходит:(

Comment: @Владимир вы куда хотите выводить сообщение, когда приложение не запущено? вот реализация для Xamarin https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/